# "Method not implemented" error when running Azure script from c#

Tags: c#, azure-powershell

I am trying to create a website to run scripts. I am retaking this, I had been working on this some 3 weeks ago and I was able to run a script and retrieve the result. Now I'm getting this "method not implemented" error, there were no changes to the code...

```
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    public static Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    public static Command login = new Command("select-azurermprofile");

    public static Collection<PSObject> UpdateVMsList()
    {
        ArrayList resourceGroups = GetRGs();
        string rgsForPS = FormatRGs(resourceGroups);

        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();

        string scr = @"C:\Users\dimas\Source\Repos\runPSsite\slnSite\slnSite\PS\Get-AzureRMVMParallel.ps1 -ResourceGroupNames " +
            rgsForPS + "; $error;";


        ps.Runspace = Runspace.DefaultRunspace;
        Collection<PSObject> res = ps.Invoke();

        // here goes the treatment of my res variable
    }
}
```

I'm using the master page, which is loaded first. I placed a breakpoint in the last line of the code, and `res` contains this:

```
{Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.PSAzureContext}
{Method 'AuthenticateAsync' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.KeyStoreApplicationCredentialProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.}
```

The first line is expected, I'm running my own login script that uses a profile created with `Save-AzureRMProfile` cmdlet.

The second line happens when I run my script `Get-AzureRMVMParallel.ps1`, but the same happens if instead I run `Get-AzureRMVM` with a valid ResourceGroup parameter.

If I open PowerShell ISE, run AzureLogin.ps1 and then call get-azurermvmparallel with the same parameters, it works.

Thank you for taking the time to read, I'll appreciate any help.

Dimas

Comment: If instead of `Get-AzureRMVm` I run `Get-AzureRMSubscription`, I receive the proper output. I am completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar issue with this part of our code, it was working earlier this week but has started failing. I think it might be related to the PowerShell being upgraded in Azure: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v4.2.0-July2017

Given that your code has stopped working, could it be related?

Update: This fixed the issue for us: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/16590229-get-azurermvm-failing-in-azure-automation